# Changing a control's property based on an "OR" of several other controls

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, triggers

I'm creating a DataGrid in which I need to highlight one cell (textblock) based on whether one of several other cells (textboxes) in the same row gets focus. Not sure where to start with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways you could approach something like this. The cleanest would be to add a property to your view model that you can bind to. A slightly messier way would be to bind all the properties involved via a MultiValueConverter.